# Использование технологии zero-copy

Tags: java, linux, netty

Прочитал про технологию zero-copy, так как собираюсь использовать ее в серверной части приложения написанной на Netty, но при прочтении возникло много мелких вопросов, прошу прощения если вопросы покажутся глупыми или я в чем-то буду путаться, я не совсем понимаю как работает эта технология:

1. В описании этой технологии написано, что файл сразу считывается из диска в сокет минуя само приложение,то есть я правильно понял что файл не записывается в оперативную память?
2. Каким образом происходит копирование в сокет? Копируется ли файл целиком или отдается кусками определенного объема, как расчитывается этот объем?
3. Контролирует ли операционная система количество запросов к файлам при нулевом копировании, допустим при большом количестве запросов к серверу, который в свою очередь отдает изображения, происходит большое количество нулевых копирований, контролирует ли ОС этот процесс, блокируя возможность нулевого копирования, пока ресурсы не будут освобождены?

Я понимаю что ответы на вопросы могут отличаться в зависимости от того какая операционная система отвечает за эту технологию, сразу отвечу меня интересует как все это устроено в Линуксе.

Comment: 1. Да; 2. Порциями размером с блок [DMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access); 3. Скорее всего на количество одновременно выполняемых операций zero-copy влияет только лимит на количество открытых файлов.

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev , а скорость считывания с файла в сокет, который находится в оперативке и скорость считывания с помощью нулевого копирования приблизительно одинаковы или один метод быстрее другого?

Comment: zero-copy всё равно будет быстрее, за счёт меньшего количества переключений контекста.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev может ответом оформите? )

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov **файл не записывается в оперативную память?** - разумеется - записывается! Фокус в том, что он НЕ записывается в память прикладного процесса. Копирование из буфера (в оперативной памяти!) файла ввода в буфер (в оперативной памяти!) файла вывода выполняется внутри ядра. Само копирование выполняется процессором DMA, а ЦП не используется.

Comment: @Nofate не уверен я, что пара моих комментариев тянуть на полноценный ответ, а дополнить мне нечем.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, откуда такая уверенность, что память не используется? Или в данном случае опираются на драйверы устройств в этом же Netty, минуя ядро ОС? Хотелось бы понять какие устройства поддерживаются (происходит обмен по DMA в режиме p2p).

Comment: @0andriy метод `transferTo` использует системный вызов `sendfile`, который в свою очередь передаёт ядру два хэндлера - файла и сокета, а уже ядро копирует данные из одного хэндлера в другой. Память используется, но только DMA-блоки драйверами сетевой карты и файловой системы.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, OK, то есть разница в том, что в пространстве пользователя никакой дополнительной памяти не используется. Спасибо за разъяснения.